# Duplicated results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

so basically im working with 2 different tables and i don't want to repeat the results, what im getting now is some results are duplicated, same person, different photos. I know its something rather stupid and ive done this several times, I just can't figure it out now(sometimes happens no?!).

```
$res=$base->query_simple("SELECT g.id, g.available, g.name, g.age, g.tagline, p.photo FROM ".$base->array_tables[2]." AS g, ".$base->array_tables[3]." as p WHERE p.id_girl=g.id AND available=1 AND active=1 LIMIT 3");
```

Comment: Seems like there are several photos for some users. How to chose?

Comment: @jarlh here is the photos table https://www.dropbox.com/s/sympcuk86a1d3yf/Screenshot%202016-08-15%2011.54.10.png?dl=0

Comment: you want each person to appear only once, with one photo? It's not clear exactly what the result should be. You're saying "some results are duplicated", but by SQL's definition, a row with the same person ID but a different photo is not a duplicate as such.

Comment: @ADyson yeah, i guess you are right, i believe ive found a solution GROUP BY g.name did solve the problem in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GROUP BY g.name did work so yeah, happy days!

Comment: You should be aware that it is not standard SQL to select columns that are not named in the GROUP BY clause - so your query may fail if the MySQL version is updated - see here how to avoid that https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html